# How prettify.js encode HTML to show on page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using [Prettify.js](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/) and css for my web site but it is not working for HTML

Let's say I have HTML like this:

```
<div style="padding:3px 0px">
  <asp:Label ID="lblTotalAns" runat="server" Text="0 Answers" CssClass="ansHeading" />
</div>
```

How it will render by prettify?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have to change `<` to `&lt;` and `>` to `&gt;` otherwise your code gets rendered by the browser. So your code has to look like this:

```
<pre class="prettyprint">
  &lt;div style="padding:3px 0px"&gt;
    &lt;asp:Label ID="lblTotalAns" runat="server" Text="0 Answers" CssClass="ansHeading" /&gt;
  &lt;/div&gt;
</pre>
```

I have created a simple example with your html source: http://jsfiddle.net/aSb76/

This can also be seen in [prettify tests source](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/source/browse/trunk/tests/prettify_test.html#561) and the [result page](http://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/tests/prettify_test.html#html).

The basic setup on howto include prettify.js is described in the [README](http://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/README.html).

I have no clue about escaping in ASP, but the first search result in Google for something 
like 'asp encode html entities' brought up `<%= Server.HTMLEncode(sValue) %>`. Maybe you can use this.

Comment: You can use a html encoder for this like http://www.opinionatedgeek.com/DotNet/Tools/HTMLEncode/Encode.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I would like to propose an alternative solution through which you could achieve the same result (that I assume) you would like to get (= syntax highlighted HTML code shown embedded in a webpage).

Github has a neat service (called Gist) that is used for saving little code snippets online and it allows:

1. syntax highlighting
2. embedding of code snippet in your HTML (with 1.)

Here you can see your example markup on Github Gist: https://gist.github.com/2012701

Here you can see it embedded in HTML: http://jsfiddle.net/6YHDu/

If the code you want to show syntax highlighted is generated dynamically (not entered manually), then forget my proposal and go with Prettify.js, otherwise Gist is a very user friendly alternative.

Answer (score 1):

You would use it like this:

In your `<head>` element:

```
<link href="prettify.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="prettify.js"></script>
```

In your `<body>` element:

```
    <body onload="prettyPrint()">
      <div style="padding:3px 0px">
       <asp:Label ID="lblTotalAns" runat="server" Text="0 Answers" CssClass="ansHeading" />
      </div>
     </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @tonymarschall I found [this](http://code.google.com/p/syntaxhighlighter/wiki/Usage) alternative if you are looking for one. They say you can use  instead of  and  you wouldn't have to decorate your code with ugly &lts Maybe there's some escape involved with Prettify.js as well? After all it is made by Google!